# How to configure the Express response object to automatically add attributes to JSON?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node.js-connect

I have an object:

```
var obj = { "stuff": "stuff" }
```

In Express, I send it the client like so:

```
res.json(obj);
```

Is there a way to configure the response object to automatically add attributes to the json it generates?  For example, to output:

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "data": { "stuff": "stuff" }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once the data has been added to the stream, that's too late to rewrap it, so you have to do it before.

Either simply with a function:

```
res.json(wrap(obj));
```

You could also add your own json method

```
express.response.wrap_json = function(obj) {
  this.json(wrap(obj));
};
```

so you can now call

```
res.wrap_json(obj);
```

Or you could replace express json implementation with yours

```
var original = express.response.json;
express.response.json = function(obj) {
  original.call(this, wrap(obj));
};
```

I would only use the last one if you want to override all json calls.