# want to monkey patch express res.json - is there a better way?

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to monkey patch express's `res.json()` and `res.render()` to combine the object with flashes and errors. So i could do this:

```
res.flash('error', 'You suck!');
res.formError('moneyInput', 'Give me more!');
... later
res.json({success: false});
```

and it would return:
`{flashes: [{error: 'You suck!'}], errors: [{'moneyInput': 'Give me more!'}], content: {success: false}}`

and likewise `res.render` would stick those things into locals for the template.

So right now - monkey patching seems like the best course. I plan to monkeypatch it in a middleware.

**Questions:**
Is there a better alternative?
Has anyone else done this?
What are the pitfalls ?  (other than having to update my code every time i upgrade express)

Comment: Take a look at this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655968/how-to-configure-the-express-response-object-to-automatically-add-attributes-to

Comment: You won't need to update your code every time you upgrade express if you are monkey patching it in memory via middleware at run time.

Comment: if the underlying implementation changes i would want to rewrite my monkey patch (possibly)

Answer (score 0):

One alternative it to store the pending data on the response object but not monkey patch the methods in there:

```
function flash (res, type, message) { //stick this in a shared module
    res._flash = {};
    res._flash[type] = message;
    return res;
}
//in some handler function
flash(res, 'error', 'You suck!');
```

However, I would say for a small number of really useful functions, just monkey patch it and take the risk. It is already convention to dynamically add data fields to the response which is where `res.body` comes when using the `bodyParser` middleware, for example. If you want to be paranoid about name collisions, just add a prefix like `res._mkFlash`.